# Is it possible to inject IDv3 into MP3 stream?

Tags: streaming, mp3, id3

I'd making a relay audio stream server (like shoutcast relaying but with customization) in PHP.
Is it possible to dynamicly add IDv3 tag's every specified pack of data (maybe every second - every 64KB)?
If it`s possible how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

IDv3 tags occur at the beginning of a mp3 but as an mp3 is just a series of frames due to the way it's possible to cut them with say mp3splt without re-encoding that stream would be IDv3 tags followed by mp3 data and then it would repeat in the same format for the next part of the stream

clearly i'm ignoring a lot of the details

Comment: Do you have any documents about it? I know MP3 structure in theory but I`m trying to implement it - no success.